# One ViewController vs. many ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm building an app which consists of different views which are closely related to each other. So far, I only have one UIViewController which controls these different views. View 1 and 2 share the same background, for instance, and the transition between view 1 and 2 is a custom animation.

My problem is that both view 1 and 2 have an UIScrollView. My UIViewController is their delegate and I could have the following scrollViewDidScroll to distinguish between the two scrollviews:

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   if (scrollView.tag == 1) 
     //handle a
   else if (scrollView.tag == 2)
     //handle b
   else if (scrollView.tag == 3)
     //handle c
}
```

As a lot happens with scrollView 1 and different things happen with scrollView2, the code will become really messy. Ideally, I'd like to define in a separate file what happens if scrollView1 is scrolled etc.. Yet I don't want to have another UIViewController as then transitions become more difficult. I don't have a NavBar or ToolBar, so neither UINavigationController nor UITabBarController would work very well in my case.

What should I do?

I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683554/showing-two-uiviewcontroller-at-the-same-time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want two view controllers, just create a separate delegate for each scroll view. Make it an `NSObject` which conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate` and create it at the same time as the scroll view.

Seems to combine the results you seek: one view controller, but encapsulated scroll view code.

Comment: So I would have the scrollViewDidScroll method in a file which I could call svController.m which I set as a delegate to my UIScrollView, right? like scrollView.delegate = svController; Sounds like a very clean solution. Thanks so much for this, will give it a go. Would you go with two ViewControllers, though? I guess a UINavigationController would be really nice in my case, if I could only customise the transitions...

Comment: To endorse this answer and push the point: the controller portion of your app needn't consist only of view controllers.

Comment: @Tommy Thanks. So there is nothing wrong then with only one ViewController. I somehow felt I need to do intricate and difficult code magic swapping other UIViewControllers from my main ViewController.

Comment: Consider how much `if .. else if .. else if` code remains in your view controller after factoring out the scroll view delegate. If it's more than 2-3 methods it might be worth trying to find a cleaner solution. I'd suggest posting a separate question about custom transitions with `UINavigationController`.

Comment: But, what Tommy said. You can design your controller layer with multiple classes, and it often leads to cleaner and more maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a base controller class that handles the common functionality. Each different controller can inherit from this and override with their specific functionality as required.

Aka [the template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

**Edit**

To expand. You say you want only one view controller. So you should create a separate class to handle the individual functionality. The View Controller has a base class pointer which gets swapped around according to the current view.

In pseudo code :

```
class BaseFunctionality
  -(void) handleDidScroll {}
end

class ScrollViewAFunctionality : BaseFunctionality
  -(void) handleDidScroll {
     // Lots of interesting technical stuff...
  }
end

class ScrollViewBFunctionality : BaseFunctionality
  -(void) handleDidScroll {
     // Lots of interesting technical stuff...
  }
end


class TheViewController : UIViewController
   BaseFunctionality *functionality;

   -(void) swapViews {

     // Code to swap views
     [this.functionality release];

     if (view == A)
        this.functionality = [[ScrollViewAFunctionality alloc] init]
     else if ( view == B)
        this.functionality = [[ScrollViewBFunctionality alloc] init]
   }

   - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        [this.functionality handleDidScroll];
   }

end
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand. So I'd have one base UIViewController? And then different controllers that inherit from this base UIViewController? How would this look like in code?